# Menu on widget that opens onclick close when select another item

Tags: javascript, wordpress, menu, onclick

in wordpress i have a menu on my sidebar, i could make it open in click instead of hover, but now i'll like to collapse submenu when select another item.

There is a part of theme.js that i got until now.

```
/* featured box fade out effect */
$('.widget_nav_menu .menu-parent-item').click(
    function () {
        $(this).find('ul').slideDown();
    }
);
```

i've tried this with no succes

```
  /* featured box fade out effect */
$('.widget_nav_menu .menu-parent-item').click(
    function () {
            if($(this).find('ul')is(':visible')) {
                $(this).find('ul').slideUp();   
            } else {
                $(this).find('ul').slideDown();
            }


    });
```

Any clue?
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
/* featured box fade out effect */
$('.widget_nav_menu .menu-parent-item').click(
    function () {
        var obj = $(this);
        // First slide up all the submenu
        $('.widget_nav_menu ul').slideUp(function() {
            // Then expanded the clicked one
            obj.find('ul').slideDown();
        });
    }
);
```

I just guess the HTML structure,  so the code may not works, but you got the idea (read the comments).

If you can give me your HTML code I can help you then.